# Entity Framework generating error for entity that does not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework

in bottom error details neither Encoding and other mentioned entities are part of my project. Still i got this error. This error is generated suddenly when i started project after few hours without changes.
This error is occurring when first entity framework based call is made.

```
 One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

Website1.Models.Encoding: : EntityType 'Encoding' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
ActionResults: : The referenced EntitySet 'ActionResults' for End 'ContentResult_ContentEncoding_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
ActionResults: : The referenced EntitySet 'ActionResults' for End 'JsonResult_ContentEncoding_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
Encodings: EntityType: EntitySet 'Encodings' is based on type 'Encoding' that has no keys defined.
ActionResults: EntityType: EntitySet 'ActionResults' is based on type 'ActionResult' that has no keys defined.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException: One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

Website1.Models.Encoding: : EntityType 'Encoding' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
ActionResults: : The referenced EntitySet 'ActionResults' for End 'ContentResult_ContentEncoding_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
ActionResults: : The referenced EntitySet 'ActionResults' for End 'JsonResult_ContentEncoding_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
Encodings: EntityType: EntitySet 'Encodings' is based on type 'Encoding' that has no keys defined.
ActionResults: EntityType: EntitySet 'ActionResults' is based on type 'ActionResult' that has no keys defined.
```

Here is complete : database class : > [HERE](http://abroadtutor.com/test.txt)

Comment: Seems that you forgot to place `KeyAttribute` for required table column IDs. Check if they're inserted properly in data model.

Comment: i crossed check twice, every entity has key attribute. and the following are not my entities

Comment: Can you provide related model class which throwing error? And what you're tried by using the corresponding model class?

Comment: here at this link abroadtutor.com/test.txt, also mentioned above now

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with the Datatype of one of the table's column that was not supported. A column was itself representing as entity, and i don't know how.

by mistake i defined the following datatype:

```
public ActionResult effectcolumn {get; set;}
```